# Using an App Token with Laravel API for extra security

Tags: php, laravel, rest, environment-variables, laravel-5.4

I have built a RESTful API with Laravel and it's working great.

There is authentication when a user wants to create or update their records.

However, I want to add one extra level of security with an Application Token.

I have placed this token in the `.env` file and want to check if the request has the `app_token="uniquestring"` in order for my API to do anything.

Basically I don't care if the user has the correct `api_token`, if the request doesn't have an `application_token` then I want it to return false.

I have a few controllers and I'm sure I can hardcode this, but is there a good way to do it in the routes by creating a group and setting a specific rule saying if `app_token != {my app token}` then return `Request denied` or something along those lines?

Any tips are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have the right approach. Bur rather make a middleware and apply it to your routes group.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( $request->header('app_token') && $request->header('app_token') == 'uniquestring') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
}
```

add it as a middleware to your routes, assuming your middleware is alias as 'apptoken' in kernel.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'apptoken']], function(){
    ... 
});
```